# Can I configure doxygen to show 0 members in the UML class diagram?

Tags: uml, doxygen

I would like to use UML like diagrams in my doxygen documentation. However, I want to use them to show the relationships of the classes and nothing else. Hence I would like to set the number of fields and member variables to be shown to zero. Can I do this?

```
UML_LOOK = YES
UML_LIMIT_NUM_FIELDS = 0
```

This does not work because 0 means "show all".

Even if I set `UML_LIMIT_NUM_FIELDS = 1` it looks annoying because I have grouped my member functions in groups and it shows up to `UML_LIMIT_NUM_FIELDS` *per group* and not in total.

My current workaround is not to use UML_LOOK, but I am looking for a better way. Maybe the developer of doxygen reads this and thinks of a way, like `UML_LIMIT_NUM_FIELDS = -1` for "no members".

Comment: Better to file an enhancement request in bugzilla as otherwise it will probably get lost,

Comment: Good idea, just did it.

Comment: Apparently nothing changed so far. Can you please give us the link to your Bugzilla enhancement request? Thank you.

Comment: Found it:  https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/6204

Comment: Wow, two years and nothing happened :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime, the issue has been addressed, see https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/6204.

Since doxygen 1.9.0, one can disable all members by configuring `DOT_UML_DETAILS=NONE`. This allows the diagrams to focus on the relationships between the classes rather than their contents.